# BSOD in nltdi.sys Vista x64

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, bsod

BSOD caused by NetLimiter's `nltdi.sys`
Error codes vary, but this is pretty constant:

```
SYMBOL_NAME: tdx!TdxSendConnection+2a0
MODULE_NAME: tdx
IMAGE_NAME:  tdx.sys
```

Stack trace includes:

```
nltdi+0x1144
```

[example](http://www.howtofixcomputers.com/forums/windows-vista/windows-tcpip-sys-problem-bluescreen-reboot-60775.html)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest thing to do -

Press <kbd>F8</kbd> at startup (After BIOS, Before Windows Logo Screen), and choose "Safe Mode".

When you are in, uninstall Netlimiter

Answer (score 0):

they say you should apply recent MS patches.

Also think of the newly installed firewalls, anti-viruses, and other software that buries deep in your system.

Additionally, use the [Magic Link](http://www.google.ru/search?hl=en&lr=&safe=off&newwindow=1&q=vista+64+tdx.sys&btnG=Search&aq=f&oq=) :)

Answer (score 0):

It's either:

- a bug in NetLimiter, in which case make sure you have the latest version
- it's not compatible with your version of Windows, in which case you should get rid of it